# google map kml - showing markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a custom google map:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=z_EaC4GN-yk4.kdw5S77qOj4o

with some markers one it.

I exported it as kml and I added it to my map.
It was working just fine, as far as I can remember...

Suddenly it stopped working and I can't get it back.

Here is google's example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nnasghst/3/

```
var map;
var src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/westcampus.kml';

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });
  loadKmlLayer(src, map);
}

function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
    var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
    var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
    testimonial.innerHTML = content;
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And here are mine, using two different kml files.

https://jsfiddle.net/nnasghst/4/ -> http://micasurfboards.com/test/kml/EriceiraTravelTips1.kml

and

https://jsfiddle.net/nnasghst/5/ -> http://micasurfboards.com/test/kml/EriceiraTravelTips.kml

The only difference between mine and google's are the coordinates and the kml file.

I've just noticed that the text used to appear as a tool tip next to the markers.
And now it appears on the side bar. Could this be the problem?
The owner of the map changed this a didn't tell me anything about it...

Comment: [with your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/EriceiraTravelTips1.kml), [with "fixed" KML (removed `<color>` tag from the icon definitions)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/EriceiraTravelTips1noColor.kml).  You might want to "star" [issue 8551](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551).

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip!

I changed the code in the file, and it's working. All markers blue...

I didn't have a color tag, but I had something like:
    <styleUrl>#icon-503-3F5BA9</styleUrl>
which I changed to
    <styleUrl>#icon-503-FFFFFF</styleUrl>

Issue stared!

https://jsfiddle.net/nnasghst/7/

Comment: The `<color>` tag is at the bottom of the file where the `<Style>` are defined (`<Style id='icon-503-3F5BA9'><IconStyle><color>ffA95B3F</color><scale>1.1</scale><Icon><href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href></Icon><hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'></hotSpot></IconStyle></Style>`)

Comment: Oh! You're right. I had missed that. What I did what change the marker's id... :P Thanks!